# How to I convert 5PM to Javascript date object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a string like

> "9:00:00 AM"

How do I convert it into a Javascript datetime object?

Currently I am using bootstrap timepicker but the control passes the value back as string

http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for every date-time related parsing and formatting (also for Angular projects). Works like a charm. Give it a try. Should work for your case:

```
moment("9:00:00 AM", "HH:mm:SS A").toDate();
```

See

```
var d = moment("9:00:00 AM", "HH:mm:SS A").toDate();
d instanceof Date // -> true
```

Comment: I like to use moment.js as well. a better way.
Is there a way to extract out the 9:00:00 AM from datetime object?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Having `Date` you can call `d.getTime()` to get, well... time :) but I guess it's not what you are asking for

Comment: Any idea how to calculate duration between two dates using moment.js? var test = moment.utc(moment("9:00:00 AM", "HH:mm:SS A").diff(moment("10:00:00 AM", "HH:mm:SS A"))).format("HH:mm:ss");
return 23 instead of 1.

Comment: Try `moment.duration(d1.diff(d2)).asHours()`

Answer (score 0):

`new Date('2015-1-15 9:00:00 AM')`

Comment: the bootstrap-timepicker only passes back "9:00:00 AM"

Comment: @in_visible then you can add current date

Comment: it causes more issues. When it get the datetime from server as "2015-1-15 9:00:00 AM" and need to extract out just "9:00:00 AM"

Comment: then cut the string to '9:00:00 AM'?

Comment: How? it is just messy way of doing things

Comment: @in_visible `"2015-1-15 9:00:00 AM".slice(10)`